# Internet explorer Shadow filter destroys image transparency?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, opacity

Internet explorer seems to not handle having two divs both with different semi-transparent backgrounds.

The top div loses all opacity.

Is there any way to fix this?

---

**Update**

Ok I found the issue: `filter: Shadow(Color=#474747, Direction=125, Strength=2);`
apparently the filters kill opacity in images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8 has many documented transparent png problems, there are a few workarounds, a quick google search wouldhelp you out, but here's one to get you started:

[How to fix transparent PNG on IE.](http://spirit.vn/en/?p=37)